# My module with rewritten url not loads layout

Tags: magento

I have created module and have rewrited url path as:

```
<rewrite>
  <xxx>
    <from><![CDATA[#^/signup/(.*)#]]></from>
    <to>/xxx/index/index/address/$1/</to>
  </xxx>
</rewrite>
```

And have described layout for this action:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

  <xxx_index_index translate="label">
    <remove name="yyy" />
```

If url is "/xxx/index/index/address/yyy" then all is ok. But if url path will be "/signup/yyy" then controller will work ok but the layout for it will not loaded.

**UPD**: I have added the handle in my controller (thanks to @mpaepper) "xxx_index_index" and then got handles by using: `Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());`

```
array(6) {
  [0] =&gt; string(7) &quot;default&quot;
  [1] =&gt; string(13) &quot;STORE_default&quot;
  [2] =&gt; string(44) &quot;THEME_frontend_private_sales_theme_1_default&quot;
  [3] =&gt; string(17) &quot;signup_test2552_index&quot;
  [4] =&gt; string(19) &quot;customer_logged_out&quot;
  [5] =&gt; string(24) &quot;xxx_index_index&quot;
}
```

The same result - default layout.

Comment: Are you sure that your layout File is loading correctly? Please indicate how you include your XML File.

Comment: Controller:
`$this->loadLayout(); $this->renderLayout();`

Xml:
`<frontend>
 <layout>
  <updates>
   <xxx>
    <file>xxx.xml</file>
   </xxx>
  </updates>
 </layout>
</frontend>`

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with these types of rewrites, but it seems that the rewrite does not set the correct layout handle.
I would try to add the handle `in your controller action` by using:

```
$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('xxx_index_index');
```